# Adding values from table to a List in batches in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table which I would like to iterate and add it to a list and send it to another function. However I would like to add only 50 values at once.

```
var numberOfRows = $("tr", table).length;
var jsonObj; //THis contains all the data in my table
for (i = 1; i < (numberOfRows/50) + 1; i++) {
    var id = [];
    for (var ele in jsonObj) {
        id.push(jsonObj[ele].id);
    }
    performAction(id);
}
```

However this iterates again from the start rather than from the point where it last left off. How can I modify this to add in the variable id 50 at a time?

Comment: create a loop inside a loop, the outer loop `will inc by 50` while the inner loop will `inc by 1` and starts at the given index of the outer loop.

Comment: @Jalil How will I know how many times outer loop will have to run? Store in another variable?

Comment: how about you delete the value after you push it? `delete jsonObj[ele]` this way , even if you will start over again , you will not get the same data

Answer (score 1):

I'd just loop once, and clean/restart the array after 50 pushes:

```
var jsonObj; //THis contains all the data in my table
var id = [];
for (var ele in jsonObj) {
    id.push(jsonObj[ele].id);
    if(++i % 50 === 0) {
         performAction(id);
         id = [];
    }
}
// Final remainder batch
if(id.length) 
    performAction(id);
```

Comment: what if the object is not divisible by 50? like 59. What will happen to the 9 items?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try the below code :
/*I am not dividing by 50 , so no matter how many numbers of elements there code will work*/
var jsonObj;
var id = [];
var i = 1;
for (var ele in jsonObj) {
    if(i == 50){
        performAction(id);
        var id = [];
        var i = 0;
    }
    id.push(jsonObj[ele].id);
    i++;
}
if(id.length > 0){//What if there are elements less than 50
    performAction(id);//id would have less than 50 elements
}
```

Comment: What if there arent 50 elements or more than 50 not divisble by 50